# Android/Web client and Zend server

Tags: android, zend-framework

I'm starting to develop a web application with Zend framework but I also want to make an Android client for my app.

The question is, **What is the better approach for this android/web client development?**

Being more specific, I would like to do most of the job with zend framework, but I also want to minimize the amount of code by using the same classes and methods for both clients.
Should I retrieve data for example, using only JSON and then leaving the view part to javaScript or is there a better way so?

Comment: For example, how would a simple login system work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend your controller with class Zend_Rest_Controller instead of Zend_Controller_Action and implement its methods for your REST android client to consume from.